# CSRF protection with custom form

Tags: jhipster

I created a custom form in app and I set it's action to an url that is mapped by one of my RestControllers. I send the form, and get the following error message in my browser:

Your request cannot be processed
Sorry, an error has occurred.

Status: Forbidden (Forbidden)
Message: Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

I took a look in chrome dev tools at the request itself and in the headers I found this:

Cookie:visited=yes; NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY=%22en%22; tmhDynamicLocale.locale=%22en%22; JSESSIONID=FB0F8F19DE9B17AE4038C0149A81D829; SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=NEY5SnBQMUExcForNWFuUzVJbWlpdz09OmErQkE0bWZhbURubzFDamd5ckNJUUE9PQ; CSRF-TOKEN=ab678757-2326-4ebe-99e5-c97c1372fc9a

Does this mean that the request got a CSRF token but with the wrong name or thi is something else entirely? How can I insert the correct CSRF token into a form or rather how should it get there automatically?

Answer (score 4):

If you just whant to see yor form working, you can disable CSRF protection to the URL form. Just add an entry on `web.ignoring()`

On `SecurityConfiguration.java`, find the `configure` method and add an entry like this:

`web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/api/yoururl/**")
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/assets/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**")
            .antMatchers("/test/**")
            .antMatchers("/console/**");`

Comment: Thanks! I'll giive it a go!